What are your most recommended resources to teach fractions?
Please share your resources for learning and teaching fractions...sites, videos, worksheets etc.
I am looking for online resource similar to this: https://worksheetgenius.com/math/fractions-add/ with fraction focused worksheets but with pizza or pie pictures. Something easy and engaging.

Could you give some context here, like is this for self-learning, at school, supplemental learning, adult education? Age of the target audience? Language preferences? Online or physical stuff?

Far too broad, especially without any specification to the level of student, prior experience, individual learning needs, curriculum expectations, or the myriad other important aspects of education.

For middle school or adults who are not adept to math

Update for Edit: In the updated question, the OP asks for "pizza or pie pictures." Personally (as based on research) I would advocate against circular models for introducing fraction equivalence or adding and subtracting fractions. Rather, I would recommend a rectangular model (e.g., brownie pan) because it adapts more readily to the multiplicative context. I don't mean that one should dedicate themselves to avoiding circular representations (pizzas are realistic representations, and pies are especially common in infographics) but I think it's important to think – for fractions and more generally – about the models we introduce and how well they will adapt to the next topic(s) of study.

I used materials through the Elementary Math Project but I do not see a place in which they can be freely and publicly accessed. Among written resources, I recommend the NCTM book:

Clarke, Carne, et al. Developing Essential Understanding of Rational Numbers for Teaching Mathematics in Grades 3-5. Essential Understandings. National Council of Teachers of Mathematics. 1906 Association Drive, Reston, VA 20191-1502, 2010. Link.

It is possible to purchase this in printed book form or in digital PDF form. As a consequence (in part) it is also possible to find a pirated copy of the text online; I think it is worth adding to one's own library.

please leave a comment if you downvote – i will try to address it by responding back or editing my post. thanks!

I have not voted up or down, but perhaps you are receiving downvotes for your recommendation of piracy.

@shoover Hm. That's possible. To be clear, I am indicating that pirated versions exist, but I think it's worth buying! (As possible.)

For helping k12 teachers understand fractions better, and also get a grasp on why that's important, I think Liping Ma's book, Knowing and Teaching Elementary Mathematics is an excellent resource.
Another book for teachers that I'd recommend is Marilyn Burns', Teaching Arithmetic: Lessons for Introducing Fractions, Grades 4-5. (She has lots of useful books on teaching math.)
For students, I love the Beast Academy curriculum. [Disclaimer: I currently work part-time for their parent company.] Here's a printable they've provided, so you can get a sense of their style.
When asking adult students to review fractions, I often turned to Key to Fractions, a set of 4 booklets.
All of these can probably be found used online quite inexpensively.
